# Call parent knockout function from within iframe?

Tags: iframe, knockout.js, parent

I have a knockout application with an iframe within it. I want to call a function in my knockout from within the iframe.

I have seen several answers on here saying using parent.myFunction() should work but I'm guessing that is if you aren't using knockout as that isn't working for me.

Here is a stripped down example: https://embed.plnkr.co/pCZCv73UpxTLOpClwxdX/

How can I make the button within the iFrame call the same function as the one outside of the iFrame?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`bindIframe` custom binding](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/153#issuecomment-4632081) below makes it pretty simple. Basically, it calls `ko.applyBindings` on the iframe document once it's loaded.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.bindIframe = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        function bindIframe() {
            try {
                var iframeInit = element.contentWindow.initChildFrame,
                    iframedoc = element.contentDocument.body;
            } catch(e) {
                // ignored
            }
            if (iframeInit)
                iframeInit(ko, valueAccessor());
            else if (iframedoc)
                ko.applyBindings(valueAccessor(), iframedoc);
        };
        bindIframe();
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, 'load', bindIframe);
    }
};
```

https://embed.plnkr.co/Hvv2Mx3NZKc9iuS61TXD/

Comment: I don't see any changes in the plunker link you provided.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way for me to call a parent function within a javascript function on the iframe or do I have to use the databind tag on an html element?

Comment: The binding I provided allows you specify a function in your child frame called `initChildFrame`. See http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/nQyyb/ for how you'd do that.

Comment: I believe I've answered your question. Please accept the answer.